# Implementing a "screen" command for windows machine using python

Tags: python, windows, ssh, cygwin, gnu-screen

So I am trying to do following:

1. I have *Cygwin* enabled with *screen* and *ssh daemon* in *Windows 7*.
2. I create a new screen using the command `screen -dmS "my_screen"` on my *Windows* machine.
3. I *ssh* to the *Windows* machine from my *Linux* machine.
4. I attach to it from my unix machine using `screen -d -r my_screen`
5. Now I try to launch a *Windows* application, for example *notepad.exe*.

Now I want to a automate this using *Python.*  The objective is to just manually *ssh* to *Windows* and then run a *Python* script which will do the above steps. I have written the following script but it is not working:

```
import shlex
import os
import time
import subprocess

cmdString = "screen -d -r default_screen"

cmdArgs=shlex.split(cmdString)

p=subprocess.Popen(cmdArgs)

cmds = "./notepad.exe"

cArgs=shlex.split(cmds)

pp=subprocess.Popen(cArgs)
```

This is not working. :( Basically to get the screen I will probably need to import pty package or tty. But pty & tty are not supported in *Windows*. I am able to attach to the newly created screen but then attempt to launch the *Windows* program like *notepad* for example fails. It hangs and the windows GUI is not launched as it would when down manually.

I am still exploring this but I will appreciate it if someone can point me to the right way to do it.

Comment: `This is not working. :(` tells us next to nothing about the issues you are seeing ...

Comment: Basically to get the screen I will probably need to import pty package or tty. But pty does not exists in windows. I am able to attach to the newly created screen but then attempt to launch the windows program like notepad for example fails. It hangs and the windows GUI is not launched as it would when down manually.

Comment: From editing the post just now I noticed one typo in the code (`subporcess` instead of `subprocess`) that would've meant that `import` would've failed when that code was run. It doesn't sound like that happened in your case, since it sounds like `screen` was run, which suggests the code you were running was not exactly what was pasted in.

Comment: Thanks Ken. No, its not failing because of that. I am just not getting the windows GUI through the script. I am able to attach to the windows and then after wards a new command prompt in unix machine opens(a new process). Basically, the path of the script to launch the notepad runs in the older command prompt but it is suppose to run in the new command prompt where the screen is now attached. But I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Following link explains the problem but the solution is not useful, as windows has no support for pty. Any other ideas?

http://fleckenzwerg2000.blogspot.com/2011/10/running-and-controlling-gnu-screen-from.html?m=1

When we try to spawn a screen process with subprocess.Popen() or similar, screen will immediately terminate. It will refuse to run without an own terminal, and subprocess.Popen() does not allocate a terminal for new processes. The obvious thing to do is to somehow allocate a new terminal, and connect the newly spawned subprocess to it.

Comment: I was able to solve this by putting the screen command in bash profile file. But I am still trying to automate attaching and detaching to new screen in a ssh session for windows platform. So, its still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the screen command in the bash profile script of cygwin user. This is working now.